# Flutter New widget does not change after successful Google login

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

**If I press the button on the login page, Google login is successful.
but Page does not change after successful login**

**When debugging, the'TestPage' constructor is called.**

1. main()
2. run 'MyApp'
3. instantiate & Render 'LoginPage'
4. Click & Execute 'signInWithGoogle'
5. Success Login
6. instantiate & Render 'TastPage'

**Why is TestPage not rendering?**

▽ import & main ▽

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/flutter_signin_button.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

▽ Login Page ▽

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  User user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SignInButton(
          Buttons.Google,
          onPressed: () {
            signInWithGoogle().then((value) => TestPage());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

▽ signInWithGoogle Function ▽

```
Future<User> signInWithGoogle() async {
// Trigger the authentication flow
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

// Obtain the auth details from the request
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;

// Create a new credential
final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);

// Once signed in, return the UserCredential
UserCredential userCredential =
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    firebaseUser = userCredential.user;
    return userCredential.user;
  }
}
```

▽ TestPage UI ▽

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Success Login',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 onPressed: () {
            signInWithGoogle().then((value) => Navigator.pushReplacement(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => TestPage())););
          },
```

Comment: Please, provide an explanation about your answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It seems to be because the [TestPage] was not wrapped with the build.